# Call a method as property or function?

Tags: python, properties

Is it possible to have a method and call it as either function or property?

```
def Foo:
  def bar(self,x=1,y=2):
    return x+y

foo=Foo()
foo.bar #should return 3
foo.bar(4,5) #should return 9
```

It seems to be impossible, because:

- foo.bar will call `__getattribute__`; if it's a descriptior, `__get__` will be called from within `__getattribute__`, meaning that bar() is evaluated before it's even returned to the caller
- if an attribute is a function, it only returns a function and *then* () is applied to that function
- because of that, it's impossible to detect in `__getattribute__` if caller is calling a property or function
- hence, dual behaviour is not possible

What I hopped to implement is something like (pseudocode):

```
def __getattribute__():
   if len(args)>1: return function
   else: return property
```

But because args are not passed to `__getattribute__` or `__get__`, I don't know where and how to switch between property and function.

Comment: The problem is indeed that `Foo` does not know what you are going to do with the attribute: the calling part is not communicated to `Foo`...

Comment: unless... if the result returned by the property had .__call__ method and the caller could choose to keep the result or call the function... it's bad and ugly and questionable... but... maybe

Comment: well you can - to some extent - generate a proxy element that calculates the default result and also attaches a `__call__` to the result. The problem is that if the function has side-effects, these will be "fired"...

Comment: there is something else going on, because setters don't invoke __getattribute__ at all! How do they work!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
foo.bar() # 3
foo.bar(4, 5) # 9
```

If you do insist, here is a very ugly, unusable solution, that wil actually return 3 and 9.  Works on python 3.6.  Don't use it:

```
class CallableInt(int):
    """But, why????"""
    def __call__(self, x, y):
        return x + y


class Foo:
    @property
    def bar(self):
        return CallableInt(3)


foo = Foo()
print(foo.bar)
print(foo.bar(4, 5))
```

Comment: Indeed, this would work, only two issues (two sides of the same coin): 1) property would always be evaluated 2)if property also call self as function, this wouldn't work at all (but then I need to elaborate on the why to make any sense out of it ;-) )