# function behavior as property or method depending on how calling it

Tags: javascript, jquery, self-invoking-function

i have javascript code as follows:

```js
(function(root, factory) {
  root.test = factory;
})(this, function() {

})
var test = function test(param) {
  var num = 0;
  if (param !== undefined) {
    num += param;
    console.log("calling test added: " + param + ", new value: " + num)
  } else
    console.log("test(without parameter) value:" + num);

  function test2(param) {
    num += param;
    console.log("calling test2 added: " + param + ", new value: " + num)
    return this;
  }

  function test3(param) {
    num += param;
    console.log("calling test3 added: " + param + ", new value: " + num)
    return this;
  }
  return {
    test: this,
    test2: test2,
    test3: test3
  };
}
//this works
test(3).test2(5).test3(7);
//below doesn't
//test.test2(5);
```

i am not sure question already asked before but i couldnt find similar problem like mine (i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42899319/call-a-method-as-property-or-function) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227699/strange-behavior-on-function-calling), but not actually what i look for)

i want to access methods of my "test" function without using parentheses like JQUERY' s "$".
for example with jquery i can use both ways:

$(...) and $.ajax(...).

in my code i want to use both test(...) and test.test2(...) ways too.

for understanding how jquery achive it, i tried to research in [jquery uncompressed development file](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js), but there are too many codes(nearly 10600 lines) and found too complex for me, so i am asking here.
I'm sorry for my bad english and Thanks for your help.

Comment: functions are objects. You can just add properties. `function f(){}; f.prop = function(){}; f.prop();`

Comment: @ASDFGerte thanks for reply, i've tried your sample code and it worked, but how to define the properties inside of that function so they can share and use variables in scope of "f"